# How can I set different pattern of input field based on the option selected from the dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, drop-down-menu

I am creating a form which has a dropdown menu for selecting region. And, next field is code for specific area in that region. and the pattern of the code for specific area differs based on the region.

for instance

ASIA -- AAAA0000
EUROPE -- AAAAA000
AUSTRALIA -- 000AAA

For aisa region each code for specific area would contain 4-alphabatic characters and 4-numeric digits.
same as for europe code for specific area would contain 5-alphabatic character and 3-numeric digits.

How can i use javascript or jquery to validate input pattern for specific area.

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  <select id="region">
  <option value="asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="australia">Australia</option>
  </select><br>
  Area:<br>
  <input type="text" name="area", id="area">
</form>

$('#region').change(function () {
 var ele = document.getElementById("region");

 if (ele.value == "Asia"){
    document.getElementById('area').pattern = '\d{4}[a-z]{4}';
 }
 else if (ele.value == "Europe"){
 }
 else if (ele.value == "Australia"){
 }

});
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx matching in javascript to find whether the value entered in the area filed matches or not.

```
`    $('#region').change(function () {
          var ele = document.getElementById("region");
          var AsiaRegex = RegExp('^([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4})$','g');
          var EuropeRegex = RegExp('^([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3})$','g');
          var hasMatched = false;
          if (ele.value == "asia"){
             var code = document.getElementById('area').value;
             hasMatched = AsiaRegex.test(code);
             //console.log(hasMatched)
          }
          else if (ele.value == "Europe"){
            var code = document.getElementById('area').value;
            hasMatched = AsiaRegex.test(code);
            //console.log(hasMatched)
          }
       })`
```

^[A-Z]{n} - matches first n characters of uppercase alphabets
[0-9]{n} - matches n numeric characters

Comment: Logic is correct, but there is bit typo error in code.